# Too many c compilers in Toolchain Android build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

`./gradlew assembleDebug` throws following error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.Open stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many c compilers in toolchain.Close stacktrace
at com.android.build.gradle.external.gnumake.NativeBuildConfigValueBuilder.findToolChainCompilers(NativeBuildConfigValueBuilder.java:223)
at com.android.build.gradle.external.gnumake.NativeBuildConfigValueBuilder.build(NativeBuildConfigValueBuilder.java:159)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.NdkBuildExternalNativeJsonGenerator.processBuildOutput(NdkBuildExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:118)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildForOneConfiguration(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:284)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildAndPropagateException(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:180)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.build(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:124)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.doTaskAction(ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.java:38)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
```

App has native c dependencies uses NDK r17c, gradle 3.5.3 and STL=c++_static.

**Note** : Invalidating caches, restarting machine, restarting studio, deleting build folders, cleaning project did not work for me